# Как вывести свойства инфоблока каталога в файл экспорта Яндекс.Маркет?

Tags: php, xml, битрикс, cms

День добрый. Сейчас занимаюсь кастомизацией экспорта в Яндекс.Маркет. Хочу добавить новый тег в xml типа vendor - бренд товара. Добавил новое свойство BREND в инфоблок, но вывести его не получается в xml файле. Подскажите как получить значение инфоблока сюда /bitrix/modules/catalog/load/yandex_run.php. Возможно его нужно как о подключить?
Пытался делать так

```
$brand_value=$arResult["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["BRAND"]["VALUE"];
$strTmpOff.= "<vendor>".yandex_text2xml($brand_value, true)."</vendor>\n";
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде вызова списка элементов

```
$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "CODE", ....., "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM","PROPERTY_*");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>$ваш_id_инфоблока, "ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y", "ACTIVE"=>"Y");
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(
    Array("SORT"=>"ASC"),
    $arFilter,
    false,
    Array(),
    $arSelect
);
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement())
{
    $arFields[] = $ob->GetFields();
    $arProps[] = $ob->GetProperties();
}
```

в массиве $arSelect кроме выборки ваших параметров должно стоять "PROPERTY_*" либо "PROPERTY_BRAND"

И я почему-то никода не ставлю DISPLAY_PROPERTIES, ставлю просто PROPERTIES

```
/*$brand_value=$arResult["PROPERTIES"]["BRAND"]["VALUE"];*/
```

В цикле должно быть

```
foreach ($arProps as $val) {
    $strTmpOff.= "<vendor>".$val["BRAND"]["VALUE"]."</vendor>\n";
}
```